# Show $A\bot B\mid C$ does not imply $A\bot B\mid C^c$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, independence

My work:

If we assume $A\bot B\mid C$ and $A\bot B\mid C^c$ hold, then

\begin{align}
P(A\cap B\mid C) &= {P(A \cap B \cap C) \over P(C)}\\
&= {P(A\cap C) \over P(C)}{P(B\cap C) \over P(C)}\\
&\Rightarrow P(A \cap C) = {P(A \cap B \cap C)P(C)\over P(B \cap C)}
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
&P(A \cap C^c) = {P(A \cap B \cap C^c)P(C^c)\over P(B \cap C^c)}\\
\Rightarrow & P(A \cap C) = P(A) - {(P(A \cap B)-P(A \cap B \cap C))(1 - P(C))\over P(B) - P(B \cap C)}\\
\end{align}

By examining the second expression for $P(A \cap C)$ we see that the $(1-P(C))$ term forces $P(A \cap C) < P(A)$, whereas no such condition was necessary with $A\bot B\mid C$ alone.

Is my thought process correct?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just give a counterexample?

Comment: I'd like my counterexample to be "principled". I suppose with the condition above I now have a way to provide such a counterexample. What I have at this point does not yet constitute a proof, right?

Comment: @zipzapboing All you've shown is that $\mathsf P(A\cap C)=\mathsf P(A)-(\mathsf P(A\cap B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C))/\mathsf P(B)$ and thus $\mathsf P(A\cap B)\leq \mathsf P(A)$ because $0\leq (\mathsf P(A\cap B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)) \leq \mathsf P(B)$ ... which is true because $0\leq \mathsf P(X\cap Y)\leq \mathsf P(X)\leq 1$ holds for *any* events $X,Y$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I'm not sure it's $\leq$ in your last statement. We need $P(C) > 0$ for the problem statement to be meaningful and that guarantees that assuming $A \bot B \mid C^c$ holds restricts $P(A \cap C)$ to strictly less than $P(A)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to show the existence of *some* probability space where $\small\mathsf P(A\cap B\mid C)=\mathsf P(A\mid C)\mathsf P(B\mid C)$ but $\small \mathsf P(A\cap B\mid C^\complement)\neq\mathsf P(A\mid C^\complement)\mathsf P(B\mid C^\complement)$.

Make one.  Take the probability space of $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and $\mathsf P\{\omega\}=(1/7)\mathbf 1_{\omega\in\Omega}$.

Find events $A, B, C$ in this space which satisfy both expressions above.

Comment: Sorry if this is too nitpicky: how do we arrive at a particular case from the initial two statements? Some intuition and trial & error would certainly work, but I was trying to find a more principled approach. Hence first deriving the additional conditions imposed by breaking the second inequality.

Comment: @zipzapboing No, the very point is that knowing whether $A\perp B\mid C$ holds is *insufficent to determine* whether $A\perp B\mid C^\complement$ holds, *and vice versa*.  Knowing how $A$ and $B$ interact in $C$ does not by itself tell you how they might behave in $C^\complement$.